# Using sequencenumbers creates two different XSDs with two Enterprise Architect versions

Tags: xsd, enterprise-architect

Google did not help me with this.

I am working with multiple people on a complex class model in Enterprise Architect for which I have to generate XSD's.
The attributes of all elements in the model have a tagged value sequencenumber with a specific sequence, which are supposed to order the attributes within the resulting XSD.

While my version of Enterprise Architect creates XSD's with the correct order of attributes according to their sequence numbers, another user using the same model and (to my knowledge) the same settings creates XSD's wherein the attributes have a different order (alphabetically).
We are, however, using different versions of Enterprise Architect. I use Professional Edition 12, while the other user uses Corporate Edition 12.1.

Are there any settings with which to ensure the tagged Value sequenceNumbers are always considered? Are there distinct differences between EA-versions regarding sequences? Or could there be another reason to explain the different outputs?

Thank you very much,

R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting at `Tools|Options|Objects` called **Sort Features Alphabetically** that might be the culprit here

[image]